# SSL certificate to convert from http to https (Tableau Server on AWS)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, tableau-api

I am hosting Tableau Server on Amazon Web Services (AWS) EC2.  My domain name is ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.xx-xxxx-x.xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com.  I would like to convert http to https, so I want to get a SSL certificate.  When I asked a certificate authority (CA), they told me that my domain includes "amazonaws.com", so I couldn't get a SSL certificate.  I then tried to get a SSL certificate from AWS, I received an error message.
[Error message.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZJuQ.png)

This was due to the fact that I couldn't request a certificate for Amazon-owned domain name ending in "amazonaws.com".

Does anyone know how to deal with this issue?

Sincerely,

Kazumi

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to understand the basics of the  process of purchasing a domain name, assigning an IP address to the domain name, purchasing an SSL certificate etc.

Below steps are the easiest and the cheapest way to make your endpoint be served by SSL on AWS infrastructure:

1. Purchase a domain name eg. knozawa.com from [AWS Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/)
2. Create a new SSL certificate **free of cost** using [AWS
   Certification Manager (ACM)](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/)
3. Add your EC2 instance which hosts the Tableau server behind an ELB. The ELB
   should be configured to accept traffic over port 443 only. Select
   the certificate created using ACM to serve for SSL traffic over port
   443.
4. Go to Route 53, and created a hosted zone entry like
   tableau.knozawa.com and add the ELB alias to the entry.

**And you are done!** You can now access your Tableau installation on your own domain name, serving traffic over SSL on the link `https://tableau.knozawa.com`

This will probably cost you and additional **USD 12.00/year** for the domain name, **$10-$20 per month for ELB** based on traffic.

Comment: Thank you, Yeshodhan.  I will try your method and let you know the result.

Comment: If i have a simple app running on EC2, Does the ELB part still mandatory ?